# "Sounds Like" or Metaphone search on Specific columns in a list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, query

I need to build "**Prevent similar Names**" functionality into "Large" **SharePoint Online** list's "New Item" view. I have three columns in the list against which I need to check an entered value for a "Sounds Like" or "similar" words and suggest user that a similar item already exists, and the user will have an option of proceeding with the given name or choose a different name for the item.
My List contains 22,000 items and will increase at pace 5-6k items per year.
I am thinking of using a "Provider Hosted" add-in but SharePoint hosted Napa method is also welcome.

Any suggestion of searching "similar" words against one or more specific columns is greatly appreciated.